# sql server access ONLY the previous record based on a selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table

```
id  short_name  long_name   category    departure   rec_order
1548    AAA AAA AA  station 10:00   1
1548    BBB BBB BB  station 11:10   2
1548    CCC CCC CC  station 12:30   3
1548    DDD DDD DD  border  15:30   4
```

I want to access only last the row (station) before the border.
Basically return only

```
CCC CCC CC  station 12:30   3
```

Because the database is rather big and even this timetable is in the real life a complicated structure and we have in indexed view for putting together all the data (here is a simplification for the sake of example) I'm looking for a higher performance solution (possibly no cross join).

I've tried the selection with lag and/or lead, as well as offset fetch but those solutions were not working as soon as I put in the where clause `where category = 'border'` as it only selects the border row.

This query is working, but I'm looking for a more optimised solution:

```
select top 1 M1.short_name  M1.long_name
from V_TIMETABLE M1 WITH ( NOEXPAND )
join 
(
select top 1 rec_order, id
from V_TIMETABLE V WITH ( NOEXPAND ) 
where   V.id = 1548
and category = 'border'
order by rec_order desc
) M2 on M1.id = M2.id
where M1.rec_order < M2.rec_order
order by M1.rec_order desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to point out an alternative solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(category) over (partition by id order by departure) as next_category
      from t
     ) t
where next_category = 'border';
```

Important note:  This will not return `id`s that have no border in them.  It will also return multiple rows for `id`s that have border multiple times.  These seem more in line with the question actually asked than always selecting one row -- and is consistent with the sample code provided in the question.

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks. But to achive exactly what I want the external select has to have a top 1 cause and within the internal one replace lead with lag and the order should be descending So I will have the last station before the EXITING border (this eliminates the multiple border issue is a train is coming from AND go to abroad.

Answer (score 4):

This works for given data

```
    ;with cte
    as
    (
    select 
    id, short_name , long_name,   category ,   departure  , rec_order,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by departure desc) as rownum
   from table where category<>'border'
    )
    select * from cte where rownum=1
```

Comment: It works, also gives a bit better result as mine (less scan count and lass logical read), but I cannot incorporate this solution in a subselect or cross apply as cte is is not allowed there)

Comment: You cannot as there is as I get a error message :Incorrect syntax near ';'. And you need a column bacause of the with keyword. Try to do select * from (cte subselect) a

Comment: you can always change query,show me the outline of how you are trying to use cte..or else you can insert this result into a  temp table

Comment: The original query is within a trigger (therefore it must run fast) where I update a main train table if the train is departed from the last station just before the border a bit like this update T set end_time = getdate() from mytable T join inserted I on T.id = i.id cross apply (cte query) C where i. station_id = C.station_id and activity = 'departure'. This kind of upgrade must only happen if there is a border in the timetable, for the dometics trains other rules apply (therefore category<>'border' doesnot work because it gives always a record which is not desired)

Comment: This will give a result even when the `id` has no row for "border".

Comment: @GordonLinoff:Thanks,but i think he needs to exclude that,so it may be correct as per assumptio